# Adding newline to lists inside Notes app

Tags: notes.app, formatting

When I'm typing a list, I very often want additional newlines between some (or all) of the items to provide some clearer separation. In many apps that allow lists, you can type Alt+Enter or Command+Enter to add a newline without adding a new list item. However, this doesn't seem to work in Notes.

**Is there something similar for the Notes app so that I can add newlines in the middle of a list without creating a new list item?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your question is about the *Notes* app on *OSX*.

When typing your list hold `Cntl + Enter` to add a newline.  After the newline, just hit `Enter` again to resume the numbering.  This will give you a blank line between numbers in the list.

[image]

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you! I could have sworn I tried that already...